# ¿Cómo puedo enviar al fondo una imagen en Word con VBA?

Tags: windows, vba, macros, microsoft-office, ms-word

Estoy intentando enviar una imagen al fondo con VBA macro en Word, pero no consigo hacerlo. Intenté grabar una macro, pero tampoco funciona.

También probar la función **ZOrder**:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack
```

El problema al utilizarlo es que solo envía la imagen detrás si se selecciona manualmente previamente la imagen.

Este es mi código:

```
Sub InsertImage()
    Dim imagePath1 As String
    imagePath1 = "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\SubEscritorio3\Ejercicios Matemáticas\Barra.png"
    ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagePath1, _
    LinkToFile:=False, _
    SaveWithDocument:=True, _
    Left:=-12, _
    Top:=439.7, _
    Anchor:=Selection.Range, _
    Width:=479, _
    Height:=21.5
    Selection.ShapeRange.ZOrder msoSendToBack

End Sub
```

¿Me pueden ayudar a solucionar este problema? De ante mano muchas gracias. Saludos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontré la forma de enviarlo al fondo con el siguiente código. Lo dejo por si a alguien le llegase a servir.

```
Sub InsertImage()

Dim oILS As InlineShape, oShp As Shape
Set oILS = Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:= _
 "C:\Users\" & LCase(Environ("UserName")) & "\Desktop\SubEscritorio3\Ejercicios Matemáticas\Barra.png", LinkToFile:=False, _
 SaveWithDocument:=True)
Set oShp = oILS.ConvertToShape
With oShp
  .WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapBehind
  .Left = -12.7
  .Top = 473
  .Height = 21.5
  .Width = 479

  
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Punes no conocía yo ese método, me lo apunto, gracias. Cierra tu pregunta dándole al check aceptando tu propia respuesta, así aparecerá como pregunta respondida. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Con éste código cargas una imagen como fondo del documento al iniciarse éste

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.UserPicture _
    PictureFile:="C:\Users\el_trasgu\Pictures\avestruz.jpg"
End Sub
```

Comment: Gracias, pero no funciona para lo que lo necesito :/